# Fluent Nhibernates loads the whole object dependencies in a for loop

Tags: c#, nhibernate, lazy-loading, fluent

I'm working in a C# project using the NHibernate ORM. I'm quite new to this framework.

I have the following table mapping:

```
this.Table("FCT_CONNECTR_TRANSF_MAP_CONCEP");
this.LazyLoad();
this.Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.TriggerIdentity().Column("ID_CONNECTR_TRANSF_MAP_CONCEP");
this.References(x => x.ConnectorTransformation).Not.Nullable().Column("ID_CONNECTOR_TRANSFORMATION");
this.References(x => x.LookUpConcept).Nullable().Column("ID_MAP_CONCEPT").Cascade.All();
this.References(x => x.MapCustomSource).Column("ID_MAP_CUSTOM_SOURCE").Cascade.All();
this.References(x => x.MapCustomTarget).Column("ID_MAP_CUSTOM_TARGET").Cascade.All();
this.References(x => x.CreatedBy).Nullable().Column("CREATED_BY");
this.References(x => x.ModifiedBy).Column("MODIFIED_BY");
this.Map(x => x.DtCreated).Nullable().Column("DT_CREATED");
this.Map(x => x.DtModified).Column("DT_MODIFIED");
this.Map(x => x.Description).Column("DSC_MAP_CONCEPT");
```

And in my C# code, I have the following code snipplet.

```
foreach (var mapConcept in mapConcepts)
{
    this.connectorTransformationMapConceptEntityRepository.Delete(mapConcept);
}
```

On the line this.connectorTransformationMapConceptEntityRepository.Delete(mapConcept); the ORM loads all dependencies (+5000 select queries).

My question: Why NHibernate needs to resolve all dependencies in order to delete the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is mapping **`.Cascade.All()`** applied to your `many-to-one` reference mapping. That `cascade` setting instructs NHibernate: "load related data and delete them on delete".

This is reason, why NHibernate must load related stuff. If cascading is a feature we NEED - we can use some optimization, batch fetching:

[19.1.5. Using batch fetching](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-fetching-batch)

> NHibernate can make efficient use of batch fetching, that is, NHibernate can load several uninitialized proxies if one proxy is accessed (or collections. Batch fetching is an optimization of the lazy select fetching strategy. There are two ways you can tune batch fetching: on the class and the collection level.
>
> Batch fetching for classes/entities is easier to understand. Imagine you have the following situation at runtime: You have 25 Cat instances loaded in an ISession, each Cat has a reference to its Owner, a Person. The Person class is mapped with a proxy, lazy="true". If you now iterate through all cats and call cat.Owner on each, NHibernate will by default execute 25 SELECT statements, to retrieve the proxied owners. You can tune this behavior by specifying a batch-size in the mapping of Person:

```
<class name="Person" batch-size="10">...</class>
```

> NHibernate will now execute only three queries, the pattern is 10, 10, 5.

So, we can extend mapping of our classes `MapCustomSource`, `MapCustomTarget` with batch size:

```
Table(...)
Id(...)
BatchSize(25)
```

Or we can even change the approach and use some more efficient way how to delete more items without loading them at all:

#### [13.3. DML-style operations](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#batch-direct)

> As already discussed, automatic and transparent object/relational mapping is concerned with the management of object state. This implies that the object state is available in memory, hence manipulating (using the SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements: INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) data directly in the database will not affect in-memory state. However, NHibernate provides methods for bulk SQL-style DML statement execution which are performed through the Hibernate Query Language (HQL).

An example of code DELETION without LOADING at all:

```
ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction();

String hqlDelete = "delete Customer c where c.name = :oldName";
// or String hqlDelete = "delete Customer where name = :oldName";
int deletedEntities = s.CreateQuery( hqlDelete )
        .SetString( "oldName", oldName )
        .ExecuteUpdate();
tx.Commit();
session.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Radim. One more question, why would we let NHibernate manage the Cascade if we have a the database which can manage this?

Comment: Good point. Really. It depends. The simple answer is: 1) cascade is about deletion - should always happen - let it on DB. it is easy, reliable, effective, fast... 2) cascade is more comples. It is about save, update, delete... that will never be managed by DB. We need our code, or use really powerful and complex stuff in NHibernate. In such scenario, we have cascading at one place, for all operations (not delete in DB). It is easier to maintain and manage... hope this helps a bit more ;)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot for the additional explanation :).

Comment: Great if that helped anyhow, sir! Enjoy mighty NHibernate ;)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is due to cascading, when you delete the parent, all children will be deleted etc.

You may need to change from `.Cascade().All()` to `.Cascade().SaveUpdate()` instead if you don't want deletes to cascade.

You can find out more about cascade behavior at [ayende.com](http://ayende.com/blog/1890/nhibernate-cascades-the-different-between-all-all-delete-orphans-and-save-update)